# How get random child from firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i try to get random child from my firebase. but i cant, i was try from many idea from stackoverflow too but still not working. for example, i want get random child from "Bahan Makanan Susu", and after get a random child i want show the value of "kalori".

This my database created

[image]

this my currently code

```
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String Sskal =dataSnapshot.child("Bahan Makanan Susu").child("3").child("Kalori").getValue().toString();
```

'child("3")' in here i create manually and i want to make it random. thankyou hope u all can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bahan Makanan Susu/3/Kalori");
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String Sskal = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        Log.i("Firebase", Sskal);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        throw databaseError.toException(); 
    }
}
```

The main changes and points to pay attention to:

- This code reads only property from the database, passing in the entire path to that node/property in to `getReference`.
- Always implement `onCancelled` as it can point out access problems for your database. If you get an exception for this, search for the error message to learn how to deal with it.
- If this also doesn't read any value, you've never been able to read or write to the database, and your database is in another region than the US, consider re-downloading your `google-services.json` file, or specifying the database URL in the `getInstance("URL here")` call in your code.
- You really shouldn't use sequential numeric keys like this. They're an anti-pattern in Firebase, as the SDKs try to interpret them as arrays. For more on this, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer :). but in here i try to get random child from "Bahan Makanan Susu" like "1", "2" or "3" randomly, as you can see from my image structure database, and after that i want get the value from "Kalori"

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there @lazycode. Did you try my code? Did it give any errors? What did it log?

Comment: I guess he is trying to say that he wants to get random node inside `Bahan Makan Susu`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot 
dataSnapshot) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int total = reff.child("Bahan Makanan Susu").getChildrenCount();
        String Sskal =dataSnapshot.child("Bahan Makanan
```

Susu").child(r.nextInt(total)).child("Kalori").getValue().toString();
});

You would have to do a check everytime though so one child doesn't get repeated but I hope you will be able to make it work.

Comment: Please let me know if this was what you wanted or I misunderstood the question.